# How to combine 2D SmoothDensityHistogram and 3D curve?

Tags: graphics3d, histograms

I am trying to combine 2D SmoothDensityHistogram and 3D curve.
This is my histogram code

```
a = SmoothDensityHistogram[tabS2S1, Automatic, "PDF",
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Hue[2/3]}, #] &),
  PlotRange -> {{0.30, -0.05}, {-60, 120}}, 
  FrameTicks -> False,
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]
  ]
```

It shows

[image]

Here is my 3D curve code

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.007], Blue, 
   BSplineCurve[tab1, SplineDegree -> 3]}],
 PlotRange -> {{-0.05, 0.3}, {-60, 120}, {-2, 7}}, 
 BoxRatios -> {2.0, 2.0, 1.5},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> {Thick, Thick, Thick}, 
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 50, FontFamily -> "Times", 
   FontColor -> "black" },
 ImageMargins -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 1800,
 Boxed -> False,
 FaceGrids -> {
   {{0, 0, -1}, {{-0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 
      0.25}, {-180, -150, -120, -90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 
      150, 180}}},
   {{-1, 0, 0}, {{-30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}
   }
```

And it shows
[image]

I want to project the histogram picture on the bottom of 3D curve where Z=-2.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You should provide some data for tab1 and tabS2S1.

Answer (score 1):

You could project the texture of the density onto a `Polygon`. I will leave it to you to figure out the details of your plot ranges and getting the curve on this plot, as I do not have your data to try myself.

It is important that the density image has no `PlotRangePadding` and that the `PlotRange` matches up with your `Graphics3D`:

```
SeedRandom[123];
sdhtexture = 
 SmoothDensityHistogram[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100, 2}], Frame -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{z}, RGBColor[1 - z, 1 - z, 1]]] // Image

Graphics3D[{Texture[sdhtexture], Opacity[.7],EdgeForm[None],
  Polygon[{{0, -50, -2}, {0, 100, -2}, {0.3, 
     100, -2}, {0.3, -50, -2}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.3}, {-50, 100}, {-2, 6}}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Boxed -> False, 
 FaceGrids -> {{{0, 
     0, -1}, {{-0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 
      0.25}, {-180, -150, -120, -90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 
      150, 180}}}, {{-1, 0, 
     0}, {{-30, 0, 30, 60, 90, 120}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}},
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: projected density image]